# Display only the latest entry in Database and constantly checking for update after every 5 mins

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form constantly receiving input from users,
I need to keep displaying the next entry comment and only that comment.
I have id, Name and Comment in my database table 'demo'

```
id  Name     Comment
1   john     hello
2   may      yo
3   dereck   all the best
```

How to display 1 entry only then after 5 mins, next entry and repeat?

Viewing.php:

```
<?php
//connection to 
require 'config.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

// Create connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//$sql = "SELECT * FROM `demo` ORDER BY `id` DESC ";
$sql = "SELECT id, Name, Comment FROM demo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);s

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><td height='150px'></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td width='30%'>&nbsp;<td>";
        echo "<td><div id='colcenter' style='background:url(viewBG.png);width:700px;height:650px;'>".$row["Comment"]."<br>From : ".$row["Name"]."</div></td>";
        echo "<td width='30%'>&nbsp;<td>";
        echo "<tr><td height='150px'></td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Just out of interest what do you think this line is for `$idCount = "SELECT id FROM demo";
`?

Comment: And also out of interest who thought this should be closed as **`Primarily opinion based`** ??? Looks like we may have a drive by muppet in the house.

Comment: oh, I was in the mids of trying out conditions

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better way.Use max():

```
SELECT Max(id) as MaxId FROM `DEMO`
```

**Edit**

first imagine it's your `.html` or your `.php` file that contains a button:

```
<script>
function Show(){
   $.post("example.php",{method:'show'},function(data){
      $("#entry").html(data)
});
}
</script>
<div id="entry">entries will be shown here</div>
<input type="button" value="Show me new entries" onClick="Show ();" />
```

and then in **example.php** you can `echo` the last entry.I think you know what you should write in `example.php` but let's give you a sample:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['method']) and trim($_POST['method'])==='show'){
    //echo the last entries
}
?>
```

Comment: this will return the greatest id, but not the entry itself

Comment: Thank you. Need a transition time between displaying entries.

Comment: @Mr.NaViD this is no sample. it is an actual project for client

Comment: @ChristopheHsu you want to send this query every 10 minutes??

Comment: or can We click a button and the next entry appears?

Comment: Yes you can.It's better to use Ajax and then it's as easy as abc:-)

Comment: if you want I can edit my post and give you an example for what you want

Comment: yes please. It will be so grateful of you! Thank You

Comment: I'm really sorry because I forgot to put the JavaScript function.Now I edit my post again.hope help you:-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the id, if it's autoincrement, to get the latest post. Do:

```
SELECT * FROM DEMO ORDER BY  id DESC LIMIT 1
```

That will give you the entry with the greatest id (= the entry last inserted).

Comment: Thank you. Need a transition time between displaying entries

Comment: what do you mean by that ? are you refering to updating the data every 10 minutes ?

Comment: yup, is that possible?

Comment: or can We click a button and the next entry appears?

Comment: i would consider this a new question, because this has something to do with javascript. You should always split your questions. You need to look into ajax requests to achieve the update.

Comment: why split the question? my question here is asking if it is possible to display next entry every 5- 10 mins.

Comment: because the first problem targets mysql, and the second javascript / html